# Grok filter for Cisco ASA

Tags: linux, cisco, syslog, graylog, grok

How can i get port from cisco ASA syslog using grok pattern.

I have tried some methods and its not working . We are using graylog for collecting log data.

Eg Log :

`%ASA-6-301014: Teardown TCP connection 1846898154 for Vodafone:107.23.89.178/443 to Management:192.168.100.244/32790 duration 0:00:02 bytes 6923 TCP FINs`

From this example log , we need to fetch 443 port.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
\%ASA-6-301014:.*%{IPV4:ip}/%{INT:port} to.*
```

You can use GrokDebugger to test your filters:

https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/